# I am trying to create a function within google app scripts that parses a specific value and places that value within my google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing

Here is a code I have written to try to get Google's geocoding API to work in an apps script.

I need the input to be another cell in Sheets, and the output to be just the value of the formatted address tag from the XML.

```
[17-08-08 11:49:17:996 PDT] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <formatted_address>Bouwmeestersstraat 3, 2000 Antwerpen, Belgium</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>3</long_name>
   <short_name>3</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Bouwmeestersstraat</long_name>
   <short_name>Bouwmeestersstraat</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Antwerpen</long_name>
   <short_name>Antwerpen</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Antwerpen</long_name>
   <short_name>AN</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Vlaanderen</long_name>
   <short_name>Vlaanderen</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Belgium</long_name>
   <short_name>BE</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>2000</long_name>
   <short_name>2000</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.2078120</lat>
    <lng>4.3962135</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.2064630</lat>
     <lng>4.3948645</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.2091610</lat>
     <lng>4.3975625</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJf011FwP3w0cR6vrD7_qIwas</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

---

```
function GEOCODE(input) {

var response = 
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?
address='
+ encodeURIComponent(input)
+'&key=AIzaSyA6yDgoz3ENOEAks0ghXR5hJ3EHdXJ66-E');

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
var xml = response.getContentText();
return XmlService.parse(xml);

return getattribute('formatted_address')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to fetch the value of `formatted_address` attribute and then later append the value to the sheet

```
function GEOCODE(input) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='+ encodeURIComponent(input)+'&key=AIzaSyA6yDgoz3ENOEAks0ghXR5hJ3EHdXJ66-E');
  var document = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText().trim());
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  //Logger.log(root.getChild('result').getChild('formatted_address').getText())

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<SPREADSHEET ID>>").getSheetByName("<<SHEET NAME>>")
  ss.appendRow([root.getChild('result').getChild('formatted_address').getText()])
  //return root.getChild('result').getChild('formatted_address').getText();
}
```

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: it works like that for about half of the addresses, then i get one of two errors. `TypeError: Cannot call method "getChild" of null. (line 10).` or `Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 0).` which i know is related to the api having a cap of 2,500 free calls a day. thank you for your help